# Sending a json object from extjs page to backend

Tags: python, json, extjs

I am new to Extjs. I wanted to know how can I send a json object to the backend from an extjs page. I am using python to connect to the databse. What I wanted to do was, if an user enters data on the form, that data to be transfered to the database. I am not getting any good tutorials online. Can someone please help??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to send Json Object from a form to the Server side for processing and saving in database.

1st way:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url : 'your-server-url-to-post-to',
  method : 'POST', //or GET, PUT, DELETE.. case sensitive
  jsonData : your-json-object
  params : {
   //your-request-parameters
  },
  success : function(response){ //callback function },
  failure : function(response) { //callback failure function}
});
```

For direct form submission:

```
Ext.form.action.submit({
form : your-form-instance,
method : 'POST',
url : 'url-to-post-to',
params : {
//your request params
}
});
```

or another way of doing it is :

```
your-form.submit({
//same config options as above, except form : your-form-instance
});
```

Read the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) for more config options to suit your needs.. Documentation is pretty good. For learning a good coding style for ext js check out the examples that are part of the download package.

Comment: @shri: please mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied so that it goes into the answered pool and help other users

Comment: the `Ext.Ajax.request({ });` did work for me, and I've been searching for three hours to make it work with `your-form.submit()`. You made my day (well my night... it's 00:07 **`(>.<)`**)